# Converting a dict to a list + ID

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code:

```py
PROJECTS_LIST = [
    project if not project.update({"project_id": project_id}) else None for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items()
]
```

where `PROJECTS` is a `dict`. The goal is to convert a `dict` like `{"project123": {"a": "b"}}` to `[{"project_id": "project123", "a": "b"}]`

I worry that this isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```py
> project if not project.update({"project_id": project_id}) else None
> ```

The above section is rather odd. I would prefer to one of the following solutions depending on Python version:

- Python 3.9+: use the [dictionary merging operator `|`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

  ```py
  project | {"project_id": project_id}
  ```
- Before Python 3.9: The, in my opinion, nicest alternate was to use dictionary unpacking:

  ```py
  {**project, "project_id": project_id}
  ```

I'd recommend having a newline before the `for`, but otherwise the code looks fine.

```py
PROJECTS_LIST = [
    project | {"project_id": project_id}
    for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items()
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Peilonrayz that a "constructive" functional
approach such as using the `|` operator is the way to go
for a list comprehension.
Comprehensions shouldn't really be about side effects -- that's
not how human minds view them, independent of what the machine does.

But let's accept that `.update()` shall be used,
and it will be used by a comprehension.
Then instead of the cryptic

```
... = [
    project if not project.update({"project_id": project_id}) else None
    for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items()
]
```

I feel this is far more clear:

```
... = [
    project.update({"project_id": project_id}) or project
    for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items()
]
```

We have an "A or B" disjunct,
where we evaluate A for side effects,
and then since it is guaranteed to `return None`
the short-circuiting `or` operator moves along and
returns the (updated) `project` value.

The original formulation had an awkward `else`
clause in order to satisfy syntax rules.

---

If we're evaluating for side effects,
a list comprehension is not a natural way to accomplish that.

Prefer:

```
for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items():
    project.update({"project_id": project_id})
```

and subsequently use a comprehension to read out the results.

Answer (score 3):

> I worry

A little worry is a good thing because it spurs you into action, like posting a question here on Code Review :)

Approaches to alleviate your worry:

- Add documentation to your code (comments/docstrings) to more clearly specify the `PROJECTS` input `dict`
- Add documentation to more clearly specify the `PROJECTS_LIST` output
- Add tests to check a variety of inputs
- Make sure the tests hit the `else` clause

I assume the `PROJECTS` input you showed is a minimal example.  Make sure to test more realistic input, with multiple projects and multiple key/values within a project (if that is supported).

Here is another possible input.  I split the long line because long lines are hard to understand and maintain.

```
PROJECTS = {
    "project123": {"a": "b"},
    "project45" : {"c": "d"},
    "project6"  : {"e": "f", "this" : "that"}
}

PROJECTS_LIST = [
    project if not project.update({"project_id": project_id}) else None
        for project_id, project in PROJECTS.items()
]

print(PROJECTS_LIST)
```